# $(this) throwing TypeError: $ is not a function in Coffeescript, Rails 3.2

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is driving me absolutely crazy.

So each time I use $(this) inside a jQuery Event, I get TypeError: $ is not a function.

Here is a sample of the code I am using:

```
$ ->
 $(".some-element").click ->
  if $(this).hasClass("someClass")
   do something
```

Which compiles to:

```
$(function() {
 $(".some-element").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("someClass")) {
   do something
  }
 });
});
```

Here is the weird thing, if I change $(this) to jQuery(this), code works flawlessly.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

***UPDATE***

I had a CKeditor element on the page which was created by using the ckeditor gem helper tag.  I commented that out and all the javascript started working.

Comment: Please add your resolution as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

There is a conflict, use the `.noConflict()` and you should solve it.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
$j("div p").hide();

// Do something with another library's $()
$("content").style.display = 'none';
```

**http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/**

---

So:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function() {
 $j(".some-element").click(function() {
  if ($j(this).hasClass("someClass")) {
   do something
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this was not the fix, but it helped me figure out the problem.

Comment: Good then! It would be useful next time!